# MongoDB how translate switch/case with expression to java driver syntax?

Tags: java, mongodb, switch-statement

I have a projection field computed from some conditions in the current document. The native mongo query works fine. But I cant implement the query in java driver 3.4. Only java driver 3.4 syntax is relevant.

The projection code for field result from switch is:

```
"SITUACAO": {
"$switch" : {
    "branches": [
        { case: {"$eq": ["$ID_STATUSMATRICULA", 0]},
          then: {
                "$switch" : {
                    "branches": [
                        { case: {"$and": [{"$eq": ["$NR_ANDAMENTO", 0 ] },
                                          {"$eq": ["$ID_STATUSMATRICULA", 0]} ] }, then: "NAOINICIADO" },

                        { case: {"$and": [{"$gt": ["$NR_ANDAMENTO", 0]},
                                          {"$lte": ["$NR_ANDAMENTO", 100]},
                                          {"$eq": ["$ID_STATUSMATRICULA", 0]} ] }, then: "EMANDAMENTO" }
                    ],
                    "default": "--matriculado--"
                }
            }
        },
        { case: {"$eq": ["$ID_STATUSMATRICULA", 1]},
          then: {
                "$switch" : {
                    "branches": [
                        { case: {"$and": [ {"$eq": ["$ID_STATUSMATRICULA", 1]},
                                           {"$in": ["$ID_STATUSAPROVEITAMENTO", [1] ]} ] }, then: "APROVADO" },
                        { case: {"$and": [ {"$eq": ["$ID_STATUSMATRICULA", 1]},
                                           {"$in": ["$ID_STATUSAPROVEITAMENTO", [2] ]} ] }, then: "REPROVADO" },
                        { case: {"$and": [{"$eq": ["$ID_STATUSMATRICULA", 1]},
                                          {"$in": ["$ID_STATUSAPROVEITAMENTO", [0] ]} ] }, then: "PENDENTE" },
                        { case: {"$and": [ {"$eq": ["$ID_STATUSMATRICULA", 1]},
                                           {"$in": ["$ID_STATUSAPROVEITAMENTO", [1,2] ]} ] }, then: "CONCLUIDO" }
                    ],
                    "default": "--concluido--"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "default": "--indefinida--"
}
```

}

The part around $and inside case statments I can draw like this:

```
    List<Document> docs = new ArrayList<>();
    docs.add( new Document("$eq", asList("$NR_ANDAMENTO", 0)) );
    docs.add( new Document("$eq", asList("$ID_STATUSMATRICULA", 1)) );
    Document doc = new Document("$and", docs);
```

but, the structure $switch / branches[] / case ... is dificult to find the way to write.
Anybody have an example like this or some idea for write this ?
Thanks

Comment: What's so difficult? Simple guide. When you see `{}` that means use `Document`. When you see `[]` that means use `List`. That is all you need to do. Another tip. Use the same sort of indentation and nesting patterns as you are using in the JavaScript notation. It's when you deviate from that "sameness" that most people go wrong with translation in strongly typed languages, like Java. Just keep the same indenting, follow the other replacement rules and you cannot really go wrong.

Comment: In other words. Write it all out in one block just like you would in JavaScript. By declaring separate variables for separate sections you are only confusing yourself. As well as anyone else reading the code later. If it looks the same as the JSON then it "reads" the same as the JSON. And most people understand that.